# Swift JSON API call returns an empty array on the first request

Tags: json, swift

I have an app that makes api calls here and there, and needs to parse the json returned.

It works just fine, except only once the request is made more than once. For example, there is an api call for an autocompletion of a search. When the first letter is typed in, an empty array is returned. When the second is typed in, the results use the previous letter typed in, as if it is delayed and is using the previous api call.

Code:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    autocompleteIngredientSearch(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!);

}

func autocompleteIngredientSearch(searchText: String) {
    let urlRequest = URL(string: "https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/food/ingredients/autocomplete?metaInformation=false&number=10&query=" + searchText)
    var request = URLRequest(url: urlRequest!)

    request.setValue("(removed this key)", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Mashape-Key")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            do {
                self.autoResults = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                self.ingredientsTableView.reloadData()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
             self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

When I print the autoResults array is is always empty after the first request no matter what, but then always populated after the first. Any help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Please show the expected JSON response. You should use Any instead of AnyObject in Swift.

Comment: Btw, `completionHandler` is executed by a background thread, you need to wrap UI-related work like `tableView.reloadData()` with `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`.

Comment: did you check if searchText is empty or not?

Comment: @Shabirjan no, but after adding checking for if it is empty or not, it still doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @OzgurVatansever so i should wrap my reloadData() with DispatchQueue.main.async throughout all my code? or just within the completion handler

Comment: @JDaniels just within the completion handler.

Comment: did you try debugging the response? what are you getting? and can you paste the request?

Comment: @OzgurVatansever That has fixed my problem! Thank you

Comment: @Shabirjan I was printing the array, which was empty after the first letter entered but then populated after the second letter was typed, except the results would be related to the previous letter entered, if that makes sense.

Comment: @JDaniels but it has nothing to do with your problem according to your explanation. You said "autoResults array is is always empty after the first request no matter what, but then always populated after the first". Please next time explain it thoroughly so we can help better.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever as in the request would be made but the array would remain empty...which is now not the case

Comment: @JDaniels where do you print it _exactly_? I think if you print it right after you do `self.autoResults = try JSONSerialization...` in the completion block, it will print the values.